# Call to undefined function factorial()

Tags: php, factorial

my code is simple. but it gives me the error above that functorial function inside the function is undefined . why ? thanks?

```
<?php

class fact
{
    public function factorial($number) { 

    if ($number < 2) { 
        return 1; 
    } else { 
        return ($number * factorial($number-1)); 
    } 
}
}

$obj =  new fact();
var_dump($obj->factorial(6));

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Referencing `factorial` will look for a global function of that name.  But you've written it as a method, so it must be called specifically on the object:

```
return ($number * $this->factorial($number-1));
```

`$this->` references the object instance it's being called within.

Answer (score 2):

The recursion call need to be prefixed with `$this` as follows:

```
<?php

class fact
{
    public function factorial($number) { 

        if ($number < 2) { 
           return 1; 
        } else { 
        return ($number * $this->factorial($number-1)); 
        } 
    }
}

$obj =  new fact();
var_dump($obj->factorial(6));
```